# Move element on tkinter form

Tags: python, tkinter

There is simple form with OptionMenu.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Tk dropdown example")

# Add a grid
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.pack(pady=100, padx=100)

# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar = StringVar(root)

# Dictionary with options
choices = {'Pizza', 'Lasagne', 'Fries', 'Fish', 'Potatoe'}
tkvar.set('Pizza')  # set the default option

popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
popupMenu.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

OptionMenu by default in center form. I try to move it(in upper left corner) with methods place and pack but it didnt work. How can I move element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `pack` and the same time `grid` remove the `pack` and it position at the upper left corner.

When you use `mainframe.pack(pady=100, padx=100)` it will position at the center.

Comment: calling `pack` won't place something in the center. It places it at the top of the unused portion of the screen unless told to do otherwise. It _might_ look centered, but that depends on a lot of factors.